# Invalid Proxy Type Exception with methods that don't exist - Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**One Update below**

I have the following class that derives from `EqualityComparer<T>` that I am (attempting) to persist using Fluent/NHibernate.

```
public class WeeklyGSFEntity : EqualityComparer<WeeklyGSFEntity>
{
    public virtual int IssueNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int Severity { get; set; }
    public virtual char PainIndex { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual int Month { get; set; }
    public virtual int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime IncidentStart { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime IncidentEnd { get; set; }
    public virtual int SRCount { get; set; }
    public virtual string AggravatingFactors { get; set; }
    public virtual string AggravatingFactorDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan MTTR
    {
        get
        {
            return (IncidentEnd - IncidentStart);
        }
    }

    public WeeklyGSFEntity()
    {
        Status = Status.New;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() { ... }

    internal static bool StaticEqual(WeeklyGSFEntity x, WeeklyGSFEntity y) { ... }
    public static bool operator ==(WeeklyGSFEntity x, WeeklyGSFEntity y) { ... }
    public static bool operator !=(WeeklyGSFEntity x, WeeklyGSFEntity y) { ... }
    public override bool Equals(WeeklyGSFEntity x, WeeklyGSFEntity y) { ... }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { ... }
    public override int GetHashCode(WeeklyGSFEntity obj) { ... }
 }

public enum Status { ... }
public enum Region { ... }
```

Now, this worked last week. Now when I go to save any entity, I get this message:

```
 The following types may not be used as proxies:
 Core.Models.WeeklyGSFEntity: method IndexOf should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
 Core.Models.WeeklyGSFEntity: method LastIndexOf should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
```

As you can see, there are no IndexOf or LastIndexOf methods... :) I've tried to override them but they don't exist to override in the first place!

Any ideas?

**Update The First**

So I dug into the IL and there is no sign of a method `IndexOf` or `LastIndexOf`. Now, before all this happened I *did* create a new class about conflicts which had a Collection of my WeeklyGSFEntities. Now this collection would have `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` methods however, I excluded both the mapping and the class from the project...

Comment: Your code shows inheritance on EqualityComparer instead of IEqualityComparer - is that right? You state otherwise in the comments. It appears that the code follows Microsoft's advice though....

Comment: @SpaceBison Oops, fixed. Thanks! Yeah, I'm following what Microsoft tell me is the best idea. Going to dig into the IL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so instead of deriving from `EqualityComparer<WeeklyGSFEntity>` I implemented `IEqualityComparer<WeeklyGSFEntity>`.
The issue disappeared...